# Is there a way to get an url out of a chrome's storage image?

Tags: javascript, css, html, google-chrome-app

I'm building a **Chrome App** and I get from a XMLHTTPREQUEST a .png file that later is stored localy using the chrome.storage API so I can use it later in case that the person who is going to use the App can acces to it without a connection to internet. The problem is that in html you always need a url that specifies where the image is stored and I have tried everything to get an url out of that .png file stored in the chrome storage but nothing works.

I'm asking for a way to get from that stored image an url to use in an html img.

This is the code in which I get the .png file and store it in chrome's storage.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'http://siteurl.com/image.png', true);
xhr.responseType = 'image/png';
xhr.onload = function(e) {
    chrome.storage.local.set({'iconImage':this.response}, function() {
        console.log('Image Saved');
    });
};
xhr.send();
```

And this is the code that gets the image out of the storage.

```
chrome.storage.local.get(function(image){
    var img = image.iconImage;

    //here is where I need to create the url so I can use it to 
      display the image in a <img>
});
```

Thank you and sorry for my english if it is not understandable.

Comment: You can convert the image to base64 string using canvas object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`chrome.storage.local` is just a key:value store. It doesn't provide any way to use a URL to access the values.

If you need to store an image in a place where a URL can reference it, you can do one of two things:

1. If you want to keep it in `chrome.storage`, and just make a temporary URL (which will be lost when you close the app), you can read the data into an ArrayBuffer, and construct a Blob object from it.

   You can get a URL from a Blob, but it just represents a handle to an object in memory, so don't expect that you can save that URL and use it forever. The memory will be reclaimed when the app is closed, and old Blob URLs won't be valid next time.
2. If you want it stored somewhere permanently, so that you can save the URL and use it in the future, then you can use the File API to write it to the filesystem.

   File objects have a `.toURL` method that will give you back a usable URL. That URL will point to an actual file, and it will be valid even after you restart the app (and until you choose to delete the file.)